# Is this sequence using tan, convergent, divergent or oscillatory?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the nature of the sequence $\left\{(-1)^n \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{n} \right )\right\}_{n \geq 1}$?
Is this sequence convergent, divergent or oscillatory?
If it divergent, does it diverge to minus infinity or plus infinity?

Comment: Look at the graph of $\tan$ near $\pi/2$ and tell us what your thoughts about this problem are.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Since n > 1, the terms have alternating sign. The argument of the tangent function is moving closer and closer to Pi/2 then, in absolute value, the terms increase more and more and go to Infinity.

I am sure you can take from here.