# Is this sequence convergent, divergent or oscillatory?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\displaystyle{\left\{n\sin\left(\pi \over n\right)\right\}}$, 
$\displaystyle{n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots}$

Is the sequence convergent, divergent or oscillatory? And why?

Comment: You just recently asked [a very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627657/). If you have spent some effort on these problems, please tell us your thoughts. If you have not yet, I think you are misusing this site and potentially hurting your learning of these topics.

Comment: I am confused with this problem.when n=1 s (1)=0 and when n=2 the term is 2 when n=3 the term is 2.59 however when n is infinity the term is 0 .that is y I am confused with this sum.i am very new to this topic and hence am finding it difficult.

Comment: That's the first term of the sequence, but you need some facts/techniques for limits of sequences. For one thing, can you state the definition of convergent/divergent? If not, you should look it up (and ideally some examples) before attempting this problem.

Comment: If sequence has a limit , then it is convergent else it is divergent.i know the concepts.but I am not very clear on how to proceed with this particular sum.

Comment: Can I say that since n tends to infinity n sin (pi/n) tends to pi, the sequence is convergent?

Answer (score 2):

Changing a finite number of the terms of a  sequence doesn't change the nature (being convergent or divergent) of this sequence so you can't find the nature of this sequence by calculating $s(1)$ or another few terms.

**Hint**

Do you know that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\;\;?$$

Comment: Can I say that since limit n tends to infinity n sin (pi/n) is pi , the sequence converges to pi.

Comment: Yes this is the correct value but can you explicit how you find it?

Comment: PI put y=1/n in limit so y tends to 0 sin (pi y)/y .

Comment: If you use my hint you should replace $x$ by $\pi/n$.

Comment: This should give you some confidence in your answer (NOT a proof): $100 sin(\pi/100)= 3.1411$

Comment: I replaced it by I/n and then multiplied and divided by pi

Comment: I got limit as pi, but it is expected that I prove that |n sin (pi/n)-pi|<e for n@> N .howw do I procced with that proof.

Comment: ${}{}{}{}$   What's $e$?

Comment: E is Epsilon where e> 0

Comment: This the definition: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\ell$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there's $N$ such that $|u_n-\ell|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$ so write this for your sequence.

Comment: I have to find N using this definition.i an mot able to find N for this sequence.

Comment: You do not have to find $N$, but simply the definition ensures that it exists!

Comment: What is your definition of sine? Can You confirm using the Leibniz criterion that $x-x^3/6\le \sin x\le x$?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Nice to see you Sami. :+)